# Cannot make unique javascript object. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple in in-page popup called like this:

```
var test = new popObject({}); //JSON options
```

and I'm having trouble because when I create two in a row, and call show() on the first one, the second one always shows. Both are created, but they aren't separate somehow, despite being called with new. What am I doing wrong here? I've included my code, but I have removed out the irrelevant functions for compactness.

```
function popObject(options) {   
//functions

show = function() {
    console.log(boxselector);
    jQuery(boxselector).css("display", "block");
    return jQuery(boxselector);
}

var hide = function() {...}
var update = function(updateOptions) {...}
var calcTop = function(passedHeight) {...}
var calcLeft = function(passedWidth) {...}
var calcHeight = function(passedHeight) {...}
var stripUnits = function(measure, auto) {...}
var destroy = function() {...}

//public functions

this.show = show;
this.hide = hide;
this.update = update;
this.destroy = destroy;

//constants

name = options.name; //name should never be changed.
boxselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]";
boxbodyselector = ".boxbody[name=" + options.name + "]";
boxtitleselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]"
boxboxselector = ".boxbox[name=" + options.name + "]"
title = options.title;
content = options.content;  
width = options.width;
height = options.height;

this.name = name;
this.selectors = [boxselector, boxbodyselector, boxtitleselector, boxboxselector]
this.title = title;
this.content = content;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

//variables

popupHtml = ...

//init code

jQuery("#dropzone").append(popupHtml); this.init = null;
jQuery(".boxbox[name=" + name + "]").css("top", calcTop(width));
jQuery(".boxbox[name=" + name + "]").css("left", calcLeft(height));
jQuery(".boxbody[name=" + name + "]").css("height", calcHeight(height));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're declaring *a lot* of variables in the global scope. Try the following code instead:

```
function popObject(options) {   
//functions

this.show = function() {
    console.log(boxselector);
    jQuery(boxselector).css("display", "block");
    return jQuery(boxselector);
}

var hide = function() {...}
var update = function(updateOptions) {...}
var calcTop = function(passedHeight) {...}
var calcLeft = function(passedWidth) {...}
var calcHeight = function(passedHeight) {...}
var stripUnits = function(measure, auto) {...}
var destroy = function() {...}

//public functions

this.show = show;
this.hide = hide;
this.update = update;
this.destroy = destroy;

//constants

var name = options.name; //name should never be changed.
var boxselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]";
var boxbodyselector = ".boxbody[name=" + options.name + "]";
var boxtitleselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]"
var boxboxselector = ".boxbox[name=" + options.name + "]"
var title = options.title;
var content = options.content;  
var width = options.width;
var height = options.height;

this.name = name;
this.selectors = [boxselector, boxbodyselector, boxtitleselector, boxboxselector]
this.title = title;
this.content = content;
this.width = width;
this.height = height;

//variables

var popupHtml = ...

//init code

jQuery("#dropzone").append(popupHtml); this.init = null;
jQuery(".boxbox[name=" + name + "]").css("top", calcTop(width));
jQuery(".boxbox[name=" + name + "]").css("left", calcLeft(height));
jQuery(".boxbody[name=" + name + "]").css("height", calcHeight(height));
}
```

Note all the `var`s that weren't there before. This defines them as local to the function, and thus local to your object (and also, essentially, private... use `this.` instead of `var` to make public members).

Anything that isn't declared with a `var` or a `this.` is considered global. So, when you called `show()`, it used the global `show`, which referenced the object that was created later.

Comment: This is so important to do it cannot be stressed enough. Always use var unless you are absolutely sure you want a global variable, and even then, you probably shouldn't be using a global variable!

Comment: even if you DO want a global variable, you should probably be doing `window.variable_name` to make it clear it's not a reassignment of a local variable.

Comment: Still feel like I'm just getting started with javascript. I had no idea about that. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

What is `boxselector`? If it's a generic selector then it would select all elements on the page, regardless if its inside of that unique object.

Comment: `boxselector` is declared later in the object. In the original code, it's an implied global. In my solution, it's a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare something without `var` or `this` within a function definition, such as

`boxselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]";`

It creates it in the global namespace (attaches it to `window`)

Try changing this line to

`var boxselector = ".boxcontainer[name=" + options.name + "]";`